# Hotspot does not work on Macbook from iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, tethering

I setup hotspot, it shows connected also on the Macbook, but no website opens, what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Do you connect to the phone via USB cable or via WiFi/Bluetooth? Is this the first time you try, or has it worked before? Did you restart both the phone and the Mac yet.

Comment: No USB cable, I have tried it a few times, but it never worked, restart thing I have attempted in the past. It works with hotspot set on Android phone, but fails with hotspot set on iPhone

Comment: If you can, try with a cable, found it to be way more reliable.

Comment: for some reason, after connecting with a usb cable, in system preferences -> bluetooth, it gets disconnected on its own, when I attempt at connecting

Comment: When connecting via cable you can select the phone as the network device in Network preferences. Bluetooth is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: it shows iPhone USB is disabled because another network is connected.

Comment: Did you try to disconnect the other network (WiFi can be disabled directly in the network pane, Ethernet can be physically unplugged)?

Comment: Wifi is disconnected, Cisco Anyconnect Socket Filter is connected, that is VPN. But I want the VPN to work while connecting, so I would not disconnect it

Comment: Hmm, some of these additional details are rather relevant for the question, an edit would help. I would try to get it to work without the VPN yet, and then take it from there.

Comment: for now I got my wifi back, so am using it